# ¿Como puedo hacer esto con javascript puro? Detectar objeto soltado de cierta clase y obtener el id

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, drag-drop

¿Como puedo hacer esto pero con javascript puro?  es decir sin JQuery

```js
$('.miclase').on('drop', function() {
    $("#info").text('el elemento clicado es de id:'+ $( this ).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Vamos a descomponer tu código en partes para transferirlo a Vanilla JavaScript, aquello a lo que llamas JavaScript puro.

Primero, podemos emplear la función [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) para obtener el elemento al que aplicaremos el evento que detecta cuando finaliza el proceso de arrastre:

```
document.querySelector('.mi-clase')
```

Este equivale a `$('.mi-clase')` de `jQuery`.

Luego, empleamos el método [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) para adjuntar el evento. Este equivale al método `on` de `jQuery`.

Puedes emplear el [API de arrastrar y soltar de Javascript.](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API). Esta documentación expone distintos eventos para la detección de acciones de arrastrar y soltar.

```
addEventListener('dragend', function(e)
```

Acá entiendo que es importante que conozcas el porqué esta implementación luce distinta a tu propuesta original. La explicación a esto es que decidí emplear el evento `dragend` en lugar de `drop` ya que tu pregunta hace referencia a detectar cuando se suelta un elemento y, este evento cumple con esto.

El parámetro `e` en `function`...

```
function(e)
```

Es un objeto que representa el evento, este contiene información de utilidad como el `target` que es el elemento que disparó el evento y `target` a su vez, contiene el `id`.

```
e.target.id
```

He creado un ejemplo que puedes probar:

```js
document.querySelector('.mi-clase').addEventListener('dragend', function(e)
{
    console.log('El elemento clicado es de id: ' + e.target.id);
});
```

```css
.mi-clase
{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="mi-clase" id="mi-id" draggable="true">
```